# How may I trigger banner notifications using FCM?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How do I show banners in my app using Firebase's FCM feature? I was able to receive and show banner notifications via the apple provided delegate method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
  completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

However, once I try to use the FCM, this method is no longer called. Instead, it's this method that receives notification information:

```
extension FirebaseNotificationManager: FIRMessagingDelegate {
  func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    let appData = remoteMessage.appData
    appData.forEach { print($0) }
  }
}
```

I can get a printout of the `appData`, but I'm not sure how to actually display the banner alert.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of research and experimentation, I've concluded that connecting to Firebase FCM is not necessary, for this scenario.

If you connect to FCM, you'll need to rely on Firebase's `applicationReceivedRemoteMessage` method to handle incoming push notifications. I still can't figure out how to display banner notifications via that method.

However, the main goal is to access the key-value pairs sent over by the push notification. It's not necessary to go through Firebase's custom object to access those.

Every `UNNotification` object has a `userInfo` dictionary (though it's fairly heavily nested):

```
let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
```

This will contain the same information found in a `FIRMessagingRemoteMessage`:

```
let appData = remoteMessage.appData
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using this for iOS 10 and working for me.

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
   willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
     withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler 
 {
        NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;

        // Print full message.
         NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

// Change this to your preferred presentation option
      completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);

}
```

Comment: Using iOS 10 also. For some reason, right after I try to use FCM, that method never gets called.